# My grid quickly disappears on page load due to incorrect force being applied?

Tags: javascript, vector, game-physics

So I'm recreating the [warping grid from Geometry Wars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDDIYHDk5mo) in a web page to further test my skills with `JavaScript` and I've hit another snag. I'm following a tutorial written in `C#` over on [TutsPlus](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-neon-vector-shooter-in-xna-the-warping-grid--gamedev-9904) that I used a long time ago to recreate it while learning XNA Framework. The tutorial is straight forward, and most of the code is self-explanatory, but I think my lack of superior education in mathematics is letting me down once again.

I've successfully rendered the grid in a 300x300 `canvas` with no troubles, and even replicated all of the code in the tutorial, but since they're using the XNA Framework libraries, they have the advantage of not having to write the mathematical functions of the `Vector3` type. I've implemented only what I need, but I believe I may have gotten my math incorrect or perhaps the implementation.

[image: Initial Grid]

The initial grid (above) should look like this until I begin interacting with it, and it does, as long as I disable the `Update` function of my `Grid`. I've stepped through the code and the issue seems to be related to my calculation for the magnitude of my vectors. The XNA Framework libraries always called it `Length` and `LengthSquared`, but each Google search I performed was returning results for calculating magnitude as:

[image: Magnitude of a 3D Vector]

Now, this is incredibly simple to recreate in code, and my `Vector3` class accounts for `Magnitude` and `MagnitudeSquared` since the tutorial calls for both. I've compared the results of my magnitude calculation to that of [an online calculator](https://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/vector/length/) and the results were the same:

> V = (2, 3, 4)
>
> |V| = 5.385164807134504

To top this off, the URL for this calculator says that I'm calculating the length of the vector. This is what leads me to believe that it may be my implementation here that is causing the whole thing to go crazy. I've included my snippet below, and it is unfortunately a bit long, but I assure you it has been trimmed as much as possible.

```js
class Vector3 {
  constructor(x, y, z) {
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
    this.Z = z;
  }
  Add(val) {
    this.X += val.X;
    this.Y += val.Y;
    this.Z += val.Z;
  }
  Subtract(val) {
    this.X -= val.X;
    this.Y -= val.Y;
    this.Z -= val.Z;
  }
  MultiplyByScalar(val) {
    let result = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    result.X = this.X * val;
    result.Y = this.Y * val;
    result.Z = this.Z * val;
    return result;
  }
  DivideByScalar(val) {
    let result = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    result.X = this.X / val;
    result.Y = this.Y / val;
    result.Z = this.Z / val;
    return result;
  }
  Magnitude() {
    if (this.X == 0 && this.Y == 0 && this.Z == 0)
      return 0;
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.X, 2) +
      Math.pow(this.Y, 2) +
      Math.pow(this.Z, 2));
  }
  MagnitudeSquared() {
    return Math.pow(this.Magnitude(), 2);
  }
  DistanceFrom(to) {
    let x = Math.pow(this.X - to.X, 2);
    let y = Math.pow(this.Y - to.Y, 2);
    let z = Math.pow(this.Z - to.Z, 2);
    return Math.sqrt(x + y + z);
  }
}
class PointMass {
  Acceleration = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  Velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  Damping = 0.95;
  constructor(position, inverseMass) {
    this.Position = position;
    this.InverseMass = inverseMass;
  }
  IncreaseDamping(factor) {
    this.Damping *= factor;
  }
  ApplyForce(force) {
    this.Acceleration.Add(force.MultiplyByScalar(this.InverseMass));
  }
  Update() {
    this.Velocity.Add(this.Acceleration);
    this.Position.Add(this.Velocity);
    this.Acceleration = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    if (this.Velocity.MagnitudeSquared() < 0.001 * 0.001)
      Velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    this.Velocity.MultiplyByScalar(this.Damping);
    this.Damping = 0.95;
  }
}
class Spring {
  constructor(startPoint, endPoint, stiffness, damping) {
    this.StartPoint = startPoint;
    this.EndPoint = endPoint;
    this.Stiffness = stiffness;
    this.Damping = damping;
    this.TargetLength = startPoint.Position.DistanceFrom(endPoint.Position) * 0.95;
  }
  Update() {
    let x = this.StartPoint.Position;
    x.Subtract(this.EndPoint.Position);
    let magnitude = x.Magnitude();
    if (magnitude < this.TargetLength || magnitude == 0)
      return;

    x = x.DivideByScalar(magnitude).MultiplyByScalar(magnitude - this.TargetLength);
    let dv = this.EndPoint.Velocity;
    dv.Subtract(this.StartPoint.Velocity);
    let force = x.MultiplyByScalar(this.Stiffness)
    force.Subtract(dv.MultiplyByScalar(this.Damping));
    this.StartPoint.ApplyForce(force);
    this.EndPoint.ApplyForce(force);
  }
}
class Grid {
  Springs = [];
  Points = [];
  constructor(containerID, spacing) {
    this.Container = document.getElementById(containerID);
    this.Width = this.Container.width;
    this.Height = this.Container.height;

    this.ColumnCount = this.Width / spacing + 1;
    this.RowCount = this.Height / spacing + 1;

    let columns = [];
    let fixedColumns = [];
    let rows = [];
    let fixedRows = [];
    let fixedPoints = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < this.Height; y += spacing) {
      for (let x = 0; x < this.Width; x += spacing) {
        columns.push(new PointMass(new Vector3(x, y, 0), 1));
        fixedColumns.push(new PointMass(new Vector3(x, y, 0), 0));
      }
      rows.push(columns);
      fixedRows.push(fixedColumns);
      columns = [];
      fixedColumns = [];
    }
    this.Points = rows;

    for (let y = 0; y < rows.length; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < rows[y].length; x++) {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == rows.length - 1 || x == rows[y].length - 1)
          this.Springs.push(new Spring(fixedRows[x][y], this.Points[x][y], 0.1, 0.1));
        else if (x % 3 == 0 && y % 3 == 0)
          this.Springs.push(new Spring(fixedRows[x][y], this.Points[x][y], 0.002, 0.002));

        const stiffness = 0.28;
        const damping = 0.06;
        if (x > 0)
          this.Springs.push(new Spring(this.Points[x - 1][y], this.Points[x][y], stiffness, damping));
        if (y > 0)
          this.Springs.push(new Spring(this.Points[x][y - 1], this.Points[x][y], stiffness, damping));
      }
    }
  }
  ApplyDirectedForce(force, position, radius) {
    this.Points.forEach(function(row) {
      row.forEach(function(point) {
        if (point.Position.DistanceFrom(position) < Math.pow(radius, 2))
          point.ApplyForce(force.MultiplyByScalar(10).DivideByScalar(10 + point.Position.DistanceFrom(position)));
      });
    });
  }
  ApplyImplosiveForce(force, position, radius) {
    this.Points.forEach(function(point) {
      let distance_squared = Math.pow(point.Position.DistanceFrom(position));
      if (distance_squared < Math.pow(radius, 2)) {

        point.ApplyForce(force.MultiplyByScalar(10).Multiply(position.Subtract(point.Position)).DivideByScalar(100 + distance_squared));
        point.IncreaseDamping(0.6);
      }
    });
  }
  ApplyExplosiveForce(force, position, radius) {
    this.Points.forEach(function(point) {
      let distance_squared = Math.pow(point.Position.DistanceFrom(position));
      if (distance_squared < Math.pow(radius, 2)) {
        point.ApplyForce(force.MultiplyByScalar(100).Multiply(point.Position.Subtract(position)).DivideByScalar(10000 + distance_squared));
        point.IncreaseDamping(0.6);
      }
    });
  }
  Update() {
    this.Springs.forEach(function(spring) {
      spring.Update();
    });
    this.Points.forEach(function(row) {
      row.forEach(function(point) {
        point.Update();
      });
    });
  }
  Draw() {
    const context = this.Container.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    context.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    for (let y = 1; y < this.Points.length; y++) {
      for (let x = 1; x < this.Points[y].length; x++) {
        let left = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        let up = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        if (x > 1) {
          left = this.Points[x - 1][y].Position;
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(left.X, left.Y);
          context.lineTo(this.Points[x][y].Position.X, this.Points[x][y].Position.Y);
          context.stroke();
        }
        if (y > 1) {
          up = this.Points[x][y - 1].Position;
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(up.X, up.Y);
          context.lineTo(this.Points[x][y].Position.X, this.Points[x][y].Position.Y);
          context.stroke();
        }

        let radius = 3;
        if (y % 3 == 1)
          radius = 5;

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.Points[x][y].Position.X, this.Points[x][y].Position.Y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill();
      }
    }
  }
}

var grid = new Grid("grid", 40);
setInterval(function() {
  grid.Update();
  grid.Draw();
}, 5);

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

function updateMouseCoordinates(evt) {
  var rect = grid.Container.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top;

  const context = grid.Container.getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
  context.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
  context.fillStyle = "#ff3333";
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
  grid.ApplyDirectedForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 5000), new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0), 50);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #213;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #213, #c13);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #213, #c13);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas onmousemove="updateMouseCoordinates(event)" id="grid" class="grid" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

I believe the issue has something to do with the `Update` method in the `Spring` and `PointMass` classes as when I stepped through my code, I kept finding that the `PointMass` objects seemed to have acceleration when they shouldn't (as in, I haven't interacted with them yet). In all honesty, I think it's the implementation of my custom `Vector3` functions in those update functions that are causing the issue but for the life of me, I can't figure out what I've done incorrectly here.

Perhaps I just need to take a break and come back to it, but I'm hoping someone here can help spot an incorrect implementation.

---

How do I prevent my grid from immediately dissipating due to forces that have not yet been exerted (as in they are just miscalculations)?

Comment: @Olian04 The recreation instructions are helpful to ensure readers are able to quickly locate the area that will initially cause the issue to occur.

Comment: There is way too much wrong with the code, well before you get to any of the maths. Add the line `"use strict";` as the first line of your questions snippet and you will start to see the many errors in your code. There are also many silent bugs that are due to the miss use of the Vector3 class (and more). The maths for `Magnitude` is just fine, the problems in your code have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is reduce the problem down. Have only a single point, slow the interval down, step through to see what's happening. The mouse doesn't appear to be doing anything. Commenting out the line `grid.ApplyDirectedForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 5000), new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0), 50);` doesn't change the output. It goes wrong in grid.Update(), for some reason grid.Update() does something even if there's no force applied, maybe that means the spring code has a bug. The bottom right point doesn't move frame one maybe that means something. The debugger is your friend. Add a breakpoint to grid.Update() and see what the code is actually doing. I know this isn't a direct answer but I hope this guides you in the right direction.

I also want to point out that usually the whole point of Magnitude Squared is so that you can compare vectors or distances without having to do a square root operation. That is, in your Magnitude function you do a Square root operation and then in your Magnitude Squared function you square it. This is is the same as simply going x^2 + y^2 + z^2

frame 1:

[image]

frame 2:

[image]